# Using Bash Script to Find Line Number of String in File

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

How can I use a bash script to find the line number where a string occurs?

For example if a file looked like this,

```
Hello I am Isaiah
This is a line of text.
This is another line of text.
```

and I ran the script to look for the string "line" it would output the number 2, as it is the first occurance.

Comment: You could just do _grep -n "line" file.txt_ and it'll give you the line numbers.

Comment: Also _grep --color=always -n "line" file.txt_ will highlight in red the occurences of the word 'line'

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Given that your example only prints the line number of the first occurrence of the string, perhaps you are looking for:

```
awk '/line/{ print NR; exit }' input-file
```

If you actually want all occurrences (eg, if the desired output of your example is actually "2\n3\n"), omit the `exit`.

Comment: I have tried using the above command, with the string 'line' stored in a variable. I had read somewhere, that when we are trying to use an external variable within an awk command, it is good to first assign the external variable to a local awk variable. As such I tried the following command: awk -v var="$external_variable" '/external_variable/{ print NR; exit }' input-file but the command didn't return the line number. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `match` rather than `//`.  For example: `awk 'match($0,v){print NR; exit}' v=$external_variable input-file` should work.

Answer (score 25):

I like Siddhartha's comment on the OP. Why he didn't post it as an answer escapes me.

I usually just want the line number of the first line that shows what I'm looking for.

```
lineNum="$(grep -n "needle" haystack.txt | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f1)"
```

**Explained:** after the grep, grab just the first line (*num:line*), **cut** by the colon **d**elimiter and grab the first **f**ield

Comment: `head -n 1` can be replaced with `-m 1` flag in `grep`

Answer (score 5):

For an exact match, I use

```
grep -wn <your exact match word> inputfile | cut -d: -f1
```

Explained:
-n print the line number
-w to only return the line with exact match

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo `grep -n -m 1 "line" file.txt | cut -f1 -d ":"` #prints the line number of the matched first occurrence
```

`-m 1` option defines: '**stop after the first match**'

Comment: The backquote ` is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.
    
The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082