# How to get the line number?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to get the line number from a file.In a file where 5 dashes(-----) is appear i want to get that line number.
For example

```
Day to Day
------------------
Month
-----
Jan
feb
mar


Year
-----
2014
2013
2012
```

so here Month and year have 5 dashes.i want to get that month and year line number.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Bash Script to Find Line Number of String in File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026370/using-bash-script-to-find-line-number-of-string-in-file)

Comment: -1 because no attempt has been made to solve own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the -n option with `grep` to make `grep` output the line number.  So, it would be something like this:

```
 grep -n ^-----$ filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk '/-{5}/{print NR, $0}' file
2 ------------------
4 -----
11 -----
```

To get only line numbers use:

```
awk '/-{5}/{print NR}' file
2
4
11
```

**EDIT:** If you want to find lines with exact 5 dashes then use:

```
awk '/^-{5}$/{print NR}' file
4
11
```

Comment: i deleted mine because it's similar to your's. If the requirement is 5 dashes then why your command gets the line number 2?

Comment: It finds at least 5 dashes in a line not exactly 5 dashes but I have added an awk version that finds lines with exact 5 dashes.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the line number, and not the text behind, you can use `cut` in complement of `grep`:

```
grep -n '^-----$' file.txt | cut -f1 -d:
```

Output:

```
4
11
```

Answer (score 2):

One of `sed`'s lesser-used commands:

```
sed -n '/^-----$/=' file
```