# How to navigate to certain point in file using curl?

Tags: bash, curl

For certain reasons I'm writing a bash script in which I need to navigate to a certain point in a UTF-8 plaintext web page (this one to be precise gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt), getting to this in the first place using curl. The command I'm currently using is:

`curl -s http://gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt|say`

how could I make it start reading from a certain point in the book (i.e the start of a chapter)

Comment: It's been a good minute since I've used curl, but this doesn't sound like something it can do. You might have to pull the file and then find other means to start reading from your certain point.

Comment: have you thought about finding the line in the file where a word is and take if from there, the "start reading" is a bit vague... check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026370/using-bash-script-to-find-line-number-of-string-in-file... you can try something like this to get the line where the title is aplicable to you case would be `awk '/Title/{ print NR; exit }' <(curl -s "http://www.gutenberg.org/zipcat2.php/2701/2701-0.txt")` and then take if from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
chapter=4
curl -s "$url" | sed -n '/^CHAPTER '"$chapter"'\./,$p' | say
```

Comment: the link is formatted as a plaintext .txt file so i dont think this would work (I've also tried it and it didnt)

Comment: Hmm works for me. On linux substituting espeak for say